# SQL SUM DATA by Hour

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, timestamp

I have 3 columns

```
ID
TIMESTAMP
CALLS
```

I need to sum up number of call by hour. 
example

```
ID         TIMESTAMP          CALLS
1     10-01-2013 01:00:23       23
2     10-01-2013 03:00:23       55
3     10-01-2013 05:00:23       2369
4     10-01-2013 04:00:23       12
5     10-01-2013 01:00:23       1
6     10-01-2013 12:00:23       99
7     10-01-2013 01:00:23       22
8     10-01-2013 02:00:23       3
```

**Output** result should be something like

```
 TimestampHOUR       Totalcalls
  10/1/2013 01:00       46
  10/1/2013 02:00       3
  10/1/2013 03:00       55
  10/1/2013 04:00       12
  10/1/2013 05:00       2369
  10/1/2013 11:00       99
```

I already tried used datepart,hour(timestamp) but I guess it is not supported by my version of oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT   TRUNC(timestamp, 'HH24') AS hour, COUNT(*) AS TotalCalls
FROM     some_table
GROUP BY TRUNC(timestamp, 'HH24')
```

Comment: I am getting error `ORA-01898: too many precision specifiers` line 3.

Comment: @user206168, yes, you should change `'DD/MM/YYYY hh24'` by `'hh24'` or simple by `'hh'`.

Comment: @Mureinik I have one question. you see how I don't have 06:00 through 10:00 PM data? is there anyway to show those times also and show count as 0?

Answer (score 1):

You should trunc your date time to hour, then group. Sample rounding to hour:

```
select TRUNC (sysdate,'hh') from dual
```

[see results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d73bdd/7/0)